# Babel runs a plugin from the preset before my plugin, can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Everything is visible in this PR, https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/pull/58, I removed the preset as a temporary workaround but I need to find a way to make it work with the preset enable (because that's what is on the most production babel cofigs)

Answer (score 0):

Because of how babel works (trigger every visitor for every node in the specific order) the classes transform get to `ClassDeclaration` before the plugin gets to `ClassMethod` and removes the `ClassMethod`. What I had to do is to look for `ClassDeclaration` then for `ClassMethod` inside the Visitor.